# Which measur unit process cycle in processor?

Tags: cpu-architecture

i have this question in my exam 
Process cycle in processor measure by:
A) pulse.
B)Rate
C)cycle
D)time
Which one is correct!
Thank's

Comment: What? You're likely talking about the clock? Take your time and have a look at [how to ask good questions](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Super User! I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by those other units. Also, I suspect you're wondering about the units for processor speed, but I'm not 100% certain. Could you please [edit] your question to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

The measurement you are probably referring to is Gigahertz (or megahertz.  This is the number of times a second the clock changes between a 0 and a 1.  Rate, pulse, cycle and time are all equivalent ways of describing this.

You can't accurately compare CPUs using only the clock speed (another common term for frequency) as different CPUs will do a different amount of work in a clock.  Also, more CPU cores mean that - for parrellel work loads - more performance.

A quick and dirty comparison can be done by using the CPU benchmark site which boils performance of a CPU down to a number. This gives a relative and raw number to compare processes - bigger is better.  How useful this is, however, may depend on your workload.